# Call a number on a website

Tags: applications, calls

Instead of having to highlight a number, copy, switch to call app, paste the number, and dial, is there a way to dial a number found on a website directly? I heard something about copyright issue with Apple, but is there another app or workaround to accomplish this?

Comment: It would be a patent issue, if anything.  That would be odd though, since Skype has browser plugins for that so I can't see how Apple's implementation would be unique enough to get patented.