# Call a phone number from app (or text)?

Tags: calls, phone-app

Is there way to call a number displayed on the phone (as part of text, although support for images would be nice too) that takes less steps than:

- long press to switch into text selection mode
- adjust selection begin and end to match the number
- tap the "copy" icon
- press/tap the "home" button
- tap the Dialer icon
- long press on the number field
- tap "Paste"
- tap the Call icon
  ?

I see there is [an app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.grenangen.clipboarddialer) that dials a number from the clipboard, but that only shaves off one or two steps.

Also this question is mentioned many times on the web, but I did not find any conclusive answer/solution.

Note: There is a [similar question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/138226/call-a-number-on-a-website) that is specific to phone numbers that appear on websites (and has no answers anyway).

Answer (score 1):

[Google Now on Tap](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6304517?hl=en)
on Marshmallow does something similar but not perfectly

Long pressing the <kbd>Home</kbd> brings up the *Google Now on Tap* with various options , one of them being calling the number listed ( others being- `text`, `share` and `add contact`). The number gets pasted on the  telephone app without any user intervention. One can directly call from there

- This is from a resturant search using an app. It works well in this case

[image]

- This is from a random telephone directory search on mobile browser (details blacked out for obvious reasons). Here, it picks up only the first number, so this option is a hit and miss , if there are several numbers in the image

[image]

Comment: Well, that covers one tenth of users (based on [Android dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) reporting 10% users having Marshmallow)...

Comment: Agreed, but pointed out one way, others may come up with alternatives